# How long will dev.mathoverflow.stackexchange.com be in private beta?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, private-beta

Unless I'm greatly misremembering, it's been like that since before MathOverflow moved to [SE 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/).

(I suspect that the site shouldn't be used anymore.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On that URL, it will never go out of private beta.

See that `dev.` at the start? It is for Stack Exchange developers and staff - as a development rig. That URL was used when testing migration of MathOverflow to the 2.0 platform and dealing with any issues that came up.

Use:

https://mathoverflow.net/

That is indeed on the SE 2.0 platform.

---

I have made a change, so dev sites will actually have a more meaningful and accurate message instead of the beta one. This is in the next build.

Comment: Could that be made more clear on that site? (I'm well aware of mathoverflow.net; that's where I learned about SE.)

Comment: @RickyDemer - What do you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest replacing "Warning: this site is currently in private beta for at least a few more days." with something like "Warning: this site is only for Stack Exchange developers and staff.".

Comment: Hmm... do you speak fluent MoonSpeak? ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Have fun with that. And the theme switcher, further down. Perhaps we will lock those down. Or not.

Comment: @Oded oh, I did have fun! Too bad I can't log in... :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nothing to see there. It is pretty much where the CI pushes builds, using an old backup of one of the SE databases.

Comment: @Oded no unicorn greeting those who log in? Disappointing! :-D